# If a set of vectors is a linear combination of another set, do they have the same span?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces

I'm trying to think about how to go about proving whether or not some list of vectors list has the same span as another (in general). For example, to prove something is a vector subspace, we need to prove the three axioms; but to prove vector $v$ has the same span as vector $u$, what must I show --that one is a linear combination of the other?

Comment: Are you asking about a single vector or a set of vectors? If one vector $u$ is a linear combination of another vector $v$, then $u$ is by definition a scalar multiple of $v$, so they have the same span.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Do you mean to ask that if in a set of vectors, say $\left\lbrace v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n \right\rbrace$, if $v_i$ is a linear combination of all other vectors, then the span of the given set is the same as the span of $\left\lbrace v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_{i - 1}, v_{i + 1}, \cdots, v_n \right\rbrace$?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I'm trying to ask what I need to show in order to prove a set of vectors V has the same span as another set of vectors U.

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer, Jaigus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two sets of vectors, $A$ and $B$, and if every vector in $A$ is a linear combination of vectors in $B$, then the span of $A$ is a subspace of the span of $B$.